# String output compare in if else statement in python

Tags: python

I am newbie in python. How can I match the character ON or OFF in variable value provided by user.

In following example I want to compare only ON or OFF in the input variable in if else statement

User input will be : Authentication = **ON**

```
user_input = input("Enter the value: ")
if (user_input == "ON"):
    print("The is enable: " +user_input)
else:
    print("The is disable: " +user_input)
```

Comment: As youre new to Python i highly recommend you not using the input like you do. But i will provide a short answer.

Comment: You can use the statement `in` like : `user_input in ('ON','OFF')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My input is " Authentication = ON" Or  " Authentication = OFF" 
I want  read  and compare only ON or OFF from the user input and print the statement using if else.

Comment: My issue resolved by below code.

`user_input = input("Enter the path of your file: ")
if user_input[-2:] == 'ON':
    print("The is enable" + "\n" +user_input)
else:
    print("The is disable" + "\n" +user_input)`